# get params from url() R function

Tags: r, url

im working with the base::url() function and i would like to obtain the params it returns when a url is passed to it.

```
foo <- url('https://www.stackoverflow.com')
foo

A connection with                                   
description "https://www.stackoverflow.com"
class       "url-wininet"          
mode        "r"                    
text        "text"                 
opened      "closed"               
can read    "yes"                  
can write   "no"
```

Is there a good way to get the **class**,**mode**,**text**.. params?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `summary` to get a `list`:

```
> summary(foo)
$description
[1] "https://www.stackoverflow.com"

$class
[1] "url-wininet"

$mode
[1] "r"

$text
[1] "text"

$opened
[1] "closed"

$`can read`
[1] "yes"

$`can write`
[1] "no"
```